# Parametric Polymorphism (Generic Programming) not supported in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, generics, polymorphism, generic-programming

I cannot find any information on Generic Programming in Javascript.
So I assume it is not supported.
Is it true? Is there anything that comes close?

Parametric Polymorphism
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism

Generic Programming
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming

Comment: Why would you need this in a late bound language with untyped variables? What are you seeking to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is dynamically duck typed. Generics don't make sense in that context. There aren't static types. It being supported or not is nonsensical.

Comment: Yeah ... It's dynamic like Ruby is.

Comment: thanks for the info. I really got that wrong. (also because I usually program in languages with static types, e.g. haskell, java, etc.).

Comment: Check the wiki pages on those typing concepts. Dynamic types can be a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
var fn = function<T>(p1) {
    var elmt = document.getElementById(typeof(T).toString());
    [...]
}
```

I think that's is not supported by [JavaScript/ECMA-262: ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this [JavaScript generic type implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39140/A-Better-JavaScript-Generic-Type-Implementation).